# Can we remove Review privilege from the Vote-Down page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, meta, privileges

**This is on Meta Stack Overflow only**

On the [privileges page for vote-down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down), it shows the review tab as being available. It is not in the top bar. If I go to [/review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review), it appears that there isn't anything to review until edits at 2k. Is this a bug in the system or a needed revision to the privileges?

This is the offending part:

> ```
>   What's this new “review” link?
> ```
>
> Review allows you to monitor posts that are likely to require additional assistance from more experienced users. You can help through editing, voting (up or down) and flagging. Look at low quality posts and see if you can propose improvements to them. Every edit suggestion will be reviewed by users with global editing privileges or more and, if accepted, will grant you 2 reputation points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're referring to Meta alone, that's not possible. The Wikis here at Meta.SO are the only ones that can be edited, and the developers eventually push the changes made here out across the network. All privileges wikis are the same on every single site at that point. You can't have a different one for different sites, or main versus meta. If there are meta-specific differences, they should just be outlined in the text.

I've gone ahead and reworded the paragraph about the review link for the 125 privilege level, since some of the information there was not relevant at all. It now mentions the two specific queues you gain access to at 125 reputation, as well as the fact that they do not exist on Meta.

Answer (score 2):

> It is not in the top bar.

It *is* in the top bar. It appears in the top bar when you reached to 125 reputation on any **main** site.

> It appears that there isn't anything to review until edits at 2k.

No when you reach to 125 reputation you can review [first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) and [late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers). Probably you are looking on Meta site's review. In Meta sites *first posts* and *late answers* reviews are not available.

> Is this a bug in the system or a needed revision to the privileges?

No it is not a bug. It is by-design.

**Edit:**

If you have any suggestion on updating privileges page, you can suggest edit on privileges page.

The privilege pages are wikis. Which can be edited via Meta privileges pages. Changes on MSO will be updated to main sites too.

Comment: Whoops, I am and was referring to Meta alone, let me add that...